# I don't understand why i get segmentation fault with a function that should only swap 2 values in a struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, swap

the read_file functin works smoothly.
but whenever i call the reorder function i get the segmentation fault.

in this code i define a struct containing 2 coordinates( x and y )
and save a file containing a bunch of coordinates in the "fleet" array, using the function read_file.

the input is a txt file of this type
x3 y4 x8 y4
x2 y7 x5 y2
x3 y4 x5 y2
x1 y8 x5 y2
x7 y4 x6 y2
x3 y5 x5 y4
x3 y1 x3 y2
x5 y2 x5 y7

but the "fleet" array i am passing to the reorder function only takes the first 3 couples.  in this case. (3 4, 2 7, 3 4)

the function reorder should take the array and evalute just the x coordinate of 2 elements of the array and swap them if the second is bigger than the first. for example

if struct[0].x < struct[1].x then
swap (struct[0].x, struct[1].x)

and then again with the following couple

if struct[1].x < struct2].x then
swap (struct[1].x, struct[2].x)

i get segmentation fault even if the reorder function is made up of just these lines

```
void reorder(struct point *fleet)
{

    struct point *temp;
    struct point temp1;
    double c;
    int i;
    if (!(temp = malloc(sizeof(struct point)))){
        free(temp);
        puts("non va");
    }
    c  =  fleet[0].x;
    temp->x = c;

    printf("%lf\n", temp->x);
   
}
```

how can i fix this segmentation fault?

here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

void Read_file(FILE *f, struct point *fleet, struct  point *hits)
{
    int i, j;
    int dim = 3;
    int dim1 = 5;
    char buf[200];



    if (!(fleet = malloc(dim * sizeof(struct point)))){
        free(fleet);
        puts("doesn't work");
    }
    if (!(hits = malloc(dim1 * sizeof(struct point)))){
        free(fleet);
        puts("doesn't work");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) { 
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
            if(sscanf(buf, "x%lf y%lf", &fleet[i].x, &fleet[i].y) != 2) {puts("non va");}   // control printf 
        printf("%lf %lf\n", fleet[i].x, fleet[i].y);

        
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
            if(sscanf(buf, "x%lf y%lf", &hits[i].x, &hits[i].y) != 2) {puts("non va");} // control printf 
        printf("%lf %lf\n", hits[i].x, hits[i].y);
    }
}


void reorder(struct point *fleet)
{

    struct point *temp;
    int i, j;
    if (!(temp = malloc(sizeof(struct point)))){
        free(temp);
        puts("non va");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    if ( &fleet[i].x < &fleet[i + 1].x) {
        temp->x = fleet[i].x;
        &fleet[i].x = &fleet[i+1].x;
        &fleet[i+1].x = temp->x;
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    struct point *hits;
    struct point *fleet;
    struct point temp;
    int dim1 =  6;
    FILE *f;
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("e niente, non sono abbaastanza gli aargomenti, mannaggia");
        }
    
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    Leggi_File(f, fleet, hits);
    reorder(fleet);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `free` when `malloc` fails?  You're just passing it the null pointer, which serves no purpose.

Comment: i modify the code as you told me and it works

Comment: but if i use a. while loop like this while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL), instead of a for loop in the read function, i get a segmentation fault. how do i fix it? i'd rather use the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `fleet` is uninitialized and has indeterminate value

```
struct point *hits;
struct point *fleet;
//...
```

So calling this function

```
reorder(fleet);
```

results in undefined behavior.

As for the function

```
void Read_file(FILE *f, struct point *fleet, struct  point *hits);
```

then it deals with a copy of the pointer `fleet`

```
Leggi_File(f, fleet, hits);
```

So changing a copy in the function does not influence on the original pointer.

You have to pass the pointer by reference that is through a pointer to the pointer.

For example

```
void Read_file(FILE *f, struct point **fleet, struct  point **hits);
```

and call it like

```
Leggi_File(f, &fleet, &hits);
```

So within the function you should write for example

```
if (!( *fleet = malloc(dim * sizeof(struct point)))){
    puts("doesn't work");
    return;
}
```

To access an element of the allocated array you can use an expression like this

```
( *fleet )[i].x
```

Also it is a good idea
to initialize initially the pointers to NULL

```
struct point *hits = NULL;
struct point *fleet = NULL;
```

Also for example pay attention that this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
if ( &fleet[i].x < &fleet[i + 1].x) {
    temp->x = fleet[i].x;
    &fleet[i].x = &fleet[i+1].x;
    &fleet[i+1].x = temp->x;
    }
}
```

for starters does not make sense due to the comparison

```
&fleet[i].x < &fleet[i + 1].x
```

It seems you mean

```
fleet[i].x < fleet[i + 1].x
```

that is you want to compare data members x of the two elements of the array.

And the loop invokes undefined behavior if the allocated dynamically array pointed to by the pointer `fleet` has exactly 3 elements. Because in this case using the expression

```
fleet[i + 1].x
      ^^^^^
```

can result to accessing memory beyond the allocated array.

Comment: i am trying to change the read_file function as you suggested but i receive this error

Comment: lotta2.c:30:41: error: member reference type 'struct point *' is a pointer; did
      you mean to use '->'?
                        if(sscanf(buf, "x%lf y%lf", &fleet[i].x, &fleet[...
                                                     ~~~~~~~~^
                                                             ->

Comment: for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
   if(sscanf(buf, "x%lf y%lf", &hits[i]->x, &hits[i]->y) != 2) {puts("non va");} //

Comment: @TommasoCashmoney You have to write for example &( *fleet )[i].x provided that fleet has the type struct point **.

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing, even for pointers themselves. In your call

```
 Leggi_File(f, fleet, hits);
```

you are passing `fleet` and trying to assign pointer to allocated memory to that pointer, and expecting that it'll reflect that in the called function. That's not true, inside the `Leggi_File`, you can modify the content pointed to by the pointer `fleet`, but any changes made to `fleet` itself will not be reflected back to the caller.

So, in the next call, `fleet`is being passed uninitialised, causing undefined behaviour.

**Solution:** You need to pass a pointer to `fleet` to `Leggi_File`, and handle that accordingly.

Something like

```
Leggi_File(f, &fleet, hits);
             ^^--------------------- pass address to pointer
```

and

```
void Read_file(FILE *f, struct point **fleet, struct  point *hits)
{
int i, j;
int dim = 3;
int dim1 = 5;
char buf[200];



if (!(*fleet = malloc(dim * sizeof(struct point)))){
    free(*fleet);
    puts("doesn't work");
}
.
.
.
```